# Add to python path mac os x

Tags: python, macos, addition, pythonpath

I thought

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/me/mydir")
```

is appending a dir to my pythonpath

if I print sys.path my dir is in there.

Then I open a new command and it is not there anymore.

But somehow Python cant import modules I saved in that dir.

What Am I doing wrong?

I read .profile or .bash_profile will do the trick.

Do I have to add:

```
PATH="/Me//Documents/mydir:$PYTHONPATH"
export PATH
```

To make it work?

Comment: `$PYTHONPATH` does not exist for me... is this normal?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Modifications to `sys.path` only apply for the life of that Python interpreter.  If you want to do it permanently you need to modify the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable:

```
PYTHONPATH="/Me/Documents/mydir:$PYTHONPATH"
export PYTHONPATH
```

Note that `PATH` is the system path for executables, which is completely separate.

**You can write the above in `~/.bash_profile` and the source it using `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Thanks a lot (forgot that). WHERE do I put that? in .profile in .bash_profile? Before Macpython?:

# Setting PATH for MacPython 2.6
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

Or after that?
Does order matter?

Comment: `.bash_profile`.  If you already have a `.bash_profile`, I believe bash ignores `.profile`.  Order doesn't matter here, because they're two different environment variables.

Comment: @Felix, note that the MacPython code he has deals with `PATH` (system path), a separate variable.

Comment: So I did add PYTHONPATH "path:$PYTHONPATH" export PYTHONPATH and AFTER I restarted my computer it worked. Big Thanks to Matthew and Felix!!

Comment: Where is /Me/Documents/mydir?  I don't have that folder on my system and $PYTHONPATH is empty

Comment: @JonathanRys, thats an example folder, you will not find it in your computer. Me: your username, /Documents: if you want to put the path inside Documents folder, /mydir: example dir.

Comment: `$PYTHONPATH` does not exist for me... is this normal?

Answer (score 26):

On MAC OS you can simply find the location of python/python3 by using the command `which python` or `which python3`. (works for Linux too)

And it should give something like:

For python

```
/usr/local/bin/python
```

For python3

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
```

**Export the path to your `bash_profile`**

In your terminal type

```
sudo nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Enter your password and paste the following lines

```
PYTHONPATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3"
export PYTHONPATH
```

Press `control + x` to exit, and press `y` for saving on being asked to save

Press `enter' to return to terminal window

Source it using the following command in terminal, run

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Path to python3 should be updated now!!

Answer (score 11):

Not sure why Matthew's solution didn't work for me (could be that I'm using OSX10.8 or perhaps something to do with macports). But I added the following to the end of the file at `~/.profile`

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/dir:$PYTHONPATH
```

my directory is now on the pythonpath -

```
my-macbook:~ aidan$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/path/to/dir', ...
```

and I can import modules from that directory.

Comment: On Mac Osx terminal, if I simply write python, then it is going to python 2.7 and if I write python3.6 then it open up version 3.6. Is there anything I can do to point python to python3.6

Comment: You would have to create an alias in your .bash_profile.

Comment: `$PYTHONPATH` does not exist for me... is this normal?

Answer (score 2):

Mathew's answer works for the terminal python shell, but it didn't work for IDLE shell in my case because many versions of python existed before I replaced them all with Python2.7.7.
How I solved the problem with IDLE.

1. In terminal, `cd /Applications/Python\ 2.7/IDLE.app/Contents/Resources/`
2. then `sudo nano idlemain.py`, enter password if required.
3. after `os.chdir(os.path.expanduser('~/Documents'))` this line, I added `sys.path.append("/Users/admin/Downloads....")` **NOTE: replace contents of the quotes with the directory where python module to be added**
4. to save the change, ctrl+x and enter
   Now open idle and try to import the python module, no error for me!!!

Answer (score 2):

Setting the $PYTHONPATH environment variable does not seem to affect the Spyder IDE's iPython terminals on a Mac.  However, Spyder's application menu contains a "PYTHONPATH manager." Adding my path here solved my problem.  The "PYTHONPATH manager" is also persistent across application restarts.

This is specific to a Mac, because setting the PYTHONPATH environment variable on my Windows PC gives the expected behavior (modules are found) without using the PYTHONPATH manager in Spyder.

Answer (score 2):

On MacOS Big Surf the file to add the "export" is `$HOME/.zprofile`

So, this should work for adding PYTHONPATH to your Mac Big Surf environment variables:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/my_folder
```

If the file doesn't exist just create it in `$HOME`, normally `/Users/my_user_name`

This change in the file name is because the default shell for MacOS Big Surf is `zsh` and not `bash`

Answer (score 1):

In my `.zshrc` file located at `/Users/your_username/.zshrc`

I add the following line: `export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/your/path"` and save it.

If the file doesn't exist, create a nameless `.txt` file and change its extension to `.zshrc`. It's a hidden file, so you need to press `cmd+shift+.` to see it.

I am using macOS Monterey.

Comment: It was very useful for my Mac (Also Monterey) with chipset M1

Comment: export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/libexec/bin"

Answer (score 0):

Saw all of the previous answer and tried it myself. But most would come to be useless.

When typing in terminal, the python accepted will be 2.7 but all new modules would be for v3.x so just type

```
python3 /path/to/file/main.py
```

This will eventually run your file in python 3 and all of the imports from installed packeges will work fine.