# Pythonpath on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, syntax-error, pythonpath

I read through [Add to python path mac os x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387695/add-to-python-path-mac-os-x) and I figured doing that is a good idea, but still IDLE gives me a syntax error for a simple call of `open(filename, mode)`, so I looked a little bit further and I found that I am able to do as stated in http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1067/_index.html and set up an environment.plist in a .MacOSX folder, so I did that in my home dir and still no changes ... I am now lost :-)

Thats what I added as my python-path in .bash_profile and the same path in my environment.plist (without the :$PYTHONPATH):

```
PYTHONPATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7:$PYTHONPATH"
export PYTHONPATH
```

EDIT:
Thats where I get the syntax-Error... works fine in the interpreter

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et 
import json

app = Bottle()

@app.route('/proPass', method ='POST')

#here happens here, need it further down in the code... which is not really relevant 
f = open('/Users/mohi/Desktop/proPass_project/server_service/systems.xml', 'rw')

def getData():
    timestamp = request.POST.get('timestamp', '').strip()
    data = request.POST.get('data', '').strip()

    if timestamp:
        processData(data, timestamp)
run()
```

The error:

```
    File "proPass_script.py", line 9
    f = open('/Users/mohi/Desktop/proPass_project/server_service/systems.xml', 'rw')
    ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Put the exact and full traceback and error in between `<pre>` and `</pre>` so we can see exactly what might be the problem. Also, add a few lines of context -- often the error is on one of the lines __before__ where it detects the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PYTHONPATH` doesn't effect whether or not you get a `SyntaxError` -- only an `ImportError`. So, if you're getting a `SyntaxError`, you've got another problem with your code. Please post the code and we'll point it out.

Edit: Your error is on this line:

```
@app.route('/proPass', method ='POST')
```

The `@` designates a decorator, which is only valid on the line immediately before a function definition (`def`), a class definition (`class`), or another decorator.

It shows the error on the first character of the `open` line because it's expecting a function or class definition there.

See the docs for [function definitions](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function) for more info on decorators.

Comment: k, didn't know that, was looking a bit around the net and I found people with similar problems and they had to set a pythonpath

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: omg ... Thank you, will keep that in mind ...I have to read the howto more precisely