# Resoving path dependencies for two different packages

Tags: python

I installed graphite and cairo on MAC OSx

graphite got installed under `/Library` while cairo got installed under `/usr/local/lib`

graphite depends on cairo at run time but looks for it under /Library and fails with

```
ImportError: module not found cairo
```

How do I resolve this? where do I set the path for graphite to look for cairo under /usr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add path to cairo to your `PYTHONPATH`. Look at [Add to python path mac os x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387695/add-to-python-path-mac-os-x)