# Old version of python 3.4 not allowing python 3.6.5 to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, installation, homebrew

I'm trying to upgrade the version of python on my Mac using homebrew. I do `brew install python3` and I see that it installs python 3.6.5. However, when I do python3 --version I get -bash: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3: No such file or directory`. Not sure how I'm suppose to resolve this. Someone posted something similar ([Unable to Run Python 3 After Homebrew Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001966/unable-to-run-python-3-after-homebrew-installation)) but the solution is to download another version of python from the website, but I don't think this solves the fundamental issue of this lingering version. Any idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: This answer may have some insight for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45649473/how-to-setup-python-path-for-2-7-on-mac

Comment: Sounds like you have an orphaned link in your path, what does `echo $PATH` give you?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I actually had `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3` in my `$PATH`. I cleared the path, so now when I do python3 --version it says `python3: command not found` which is progress I guess. Still working on it.

Comment: @Brosef yes, try adding the homebrew executable to your $PATH. I believe you want `/usr/local/opt/` based on the link posted by Turksarama. Apparently, homebrew doesn't do this automatically anymore.