# from numpy.core.numeric import NaN ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, visual-studio-code

I installed all packages with `conda` and `pip` and even removed and reinstalled all of them.

After that I created a new envierment (`conda create env -- newENV`) with no packages and installed them from zero. I also tried `conda update -all`
but I get this error again:

```
from numpy.core.numeric import NaN
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I deleted Visual Studio Code and installed it again too

Comment: Have you added the conda or pip site-packages path to your environment variables path ?

Comment: Yes!! My script run well for 3 years until yesterday!!! Now I get this error :/
i don't know why this problem cured!!!

Comment: Are you able to access other installed packages ? or the problem is with them too ?

Comment: yes for all off them!! even i have one line code as:
<< import pandas as pd >>
i get this error for it too :?

Comment: It very much looks like path problem, your path might have been disturbed for some reason, if you could again set that path in your environment variables your problem would be resolved.

Comment: Do you know how change path in mac??? I try it but default path is true

Comment: Try this out -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387695/add-to-python-path-mac-os-x it might help

Comment: @Alonso Have you selected the conda environment(the bottom-left on VSCode) which you have installed the packages? And have you checked the packages in the conda environment? You can get the packages list through `conda list -n {environment}`.

Comment: @Me8saM Please check the comment above.

Comment: I delete all python package and all env also base env!! Create and install new! It works!!! Thanks a lot everyone