# I installed python yesterday off the official website and since I haven't been able to get it to run and after trial and error this is where im at

Tags: python

Im completely new to coding so I have been trying to research how to link python to python 3 and just can't get it to work is there a fix for this or a way to restart?I have also tried homebrew/pyenv and that is what I believe is causing the message im now getting in terminal

[image: terminal window showing python version 3.8]

Comment: did you try ```python3 --version```?

Comment: Seems like your system doesn't know where python is so it can't run any files. You need to update your path so python can run. Some good resources here: https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-add-python-to-the-path-variable-in-mac, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387695/add-to-python-path-mac-os-x

Comment: @BhusalC_Bipin Yeah it reads python 3.10.5

Comment: okay, what is the issue here? I am little confused.

Comment: Sorry im new to all of this im attempting to run python 3 default inside of python 1. When I wad coding it searches for "python" and says its not found so that image just shows how I messed up

Comment: depending on your application, you may want to check out an integrated environment manager such as [`anaconda`](https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution), or [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html), it's free & open source sibling. This will manage your environment for you and help resolve path issues such as this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, As I can see from the attached image, you are using MacOs.

You can start from: https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/

And download latest Python 3! which is 3.10.5 at the moment.

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3105/

Apperently there is no python installed your env. , or it cannot see the python path.

edit: Thanks to Taylor D. s feedback this URL explains the problem:
[Add to python path mac os x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387695/add-to-python-path-mac-os-x)