# Can't import modules in VSC but they have been install via pipenv

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pipenv

My operation system is macOs Ventura

This problem happens as i think only with VSC, becuase opening same folder via PyCharm all is importing successfully.

[Screenshot of Error, `pipenv --venv`, `pipenv --wheree` and `pipenv --graph`]:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PR3Vh.png

I have created directory (folder), created local virtual environment via `pipenv install django` and active its via `pipenv shell`. Imports working good ... but just in PyCharm.

I have tried to reinstall VSC — not helped.
I have assumed that in `sys.path` wasn’t written this path `/Users/sheenaz/.local/share/virtualenvs/Polls-njzI0GZr/lib/python3.11/site-packages` — it was.
I have tried to reinstall pipenv and django — not helped.

As you can see that interpretator has entered correctly, but still doesn’t work (modules not importing).

I want that my modules will able to importing, can sombedy help?

#### I know answer!

At first it's a problem not with VSC or pipenv, It's just a problem with Code Runner extension that I use.

So, by deafault Code Runner python executor map is `python` or `python3`, you need substitute this by your virual environment executor or inerpreter.

To fix this go to the settings.json or to VSC code and in settings search type `Code-runner: Executor Map`. Now you in settings.json either or again).
Search for key `"code-runner.executorMap"` in dict and as you have finded then search key `"python"` and by default you will get defeault value like `"python"` or `"python3"` maybe. You need to change this value to your python virtual environment executor map (interpreter).
In my instance it is the pipenv interpreter — `/Users/sheenaz/.local/share/virtualenvs/PLPY-ELrCBZFZ/bin/python3`

Answer (score 0):

Install specific debugger in VSCode. In my situation, debugger for OpevCV:

[image]

Because in Pycharm you install package with everything needed, while in VSC you need to additionally install the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem on MacOS Ventura, had no problem running the same environment on MacOS Monterey, where imports work. Here assumed it's a path issue, after solving dependencies
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/dir:$PYTHONPATH

then activate imports, by specifying both interpreter and path in VSCode (I have anaconda on Ventura and Python through Brew on the Monterey setup). Both now work.

Comment: Oh, I'm verry glad that you have answered but I not understand you. I must to set this environment variable in ~/.bash_profile? Or Where?

Comment: Please see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387695/add-to-python-path-mac-os-x