# python runs older version after installing updated version on Mac

Tags: python, terminal, pip, homebrew, python-venv

I am currently running python 3.6 on my Mac, and installed the latest version of Python (3.11) by downloading and installing through the [official python releases](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3110/).  Running `python3.11` opens the interpreter in 3.11, and `python3.11 --version` returns `Python 3.11.0`, but `python -V` in terminal returns `Python 3.6.1 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.`.

I tried to install again via homebrew using `brew install python@3.11` but got the same results.

More frustrating, when I try to open a virtual environment using `python3 -m venv env` I get

```
Error: Command '['/Users/User/env/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I altered `.bash_profile` with

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.11
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
. "$HOME/.cargo/env"
```

And created a `.zprofile` [based on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67692362/6069097) with

```
export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/Users/User
```

and a `.zshrc` [based on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71842117/6069097), but `--version` still throws `python3.6`.

I'm running Big Sur OS. Pip and homebrew are up to date and upgraded. Acknowledging that I'm totally foolish, what do I need to do to get python >3.7 running in terminal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## What you want to do is overwrite a python symlink.

After installing python via homebrew, you can see that python3.11 is just symlink.

```
cd /usr/local/bin; ls -l | grep python3.11
```

The result is:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  admin        43 Nov  7 15:43 python3.11@ -> ../Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.0/bin/python3.11
```

So let's just overwrite it.

```
ln -s -f $(which python3.11) $(which python)
ln -s -f $(which python3.11) $(which python3)
ln -s -f $(which pip3.11) $(which pip)
ln -s -f $(which pip3.11) $(which pip3)
```

After these commands, `pip`, `pip3`, `python3`, `python` will invoke the version 3.11.

This command makes soft symlink.

```
ln -s
```

This command with `-f` option overwrite an existing soft symlink.

A soft symlink is similar to a shortcut.

In man page,`which` command is described as

> which - shows the full path of (shell) commands.

Comment: I had to modify `cd /usr/local/bin; ll | grep python3.11` to `cd /usr/local/bin; ls -l | grep python3.11` but it works!