# How can I uninstall pip on Mac (Issue)?

Tags: macos, pip

I am trying to fix pip but I'm in a state where it's installed but also not installed?

When I type "pip" in terminal, I get that pip is not installed.
When I type "pip3" in the terminal, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

How do I get rid of pip?

I also tried to run "python3 get-pip.py" again (download again), but I got the following error:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/folders/bh/gw4lmfss1w7gkzxnv7vdftbw0000gn/T/tmpgvtrdkgq/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 160, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/folders/bh/gw4lmfss1w7gkzxnv7vdftbw0000gn/T/tmpgvtrdkgq/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 247, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/folders/bh/gw4lmfss1w7gkzxnv7vdftbw0000gn/T/tmpgvtrdkgq/pip.zip/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 553, in run
    self._handle_target_dir(
  File "/var/folders/bh/gw4lmfss1w7gkzxnv7vdftbw0000gn/T/tmpgvtrdkgq/pip.zip/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 608, in _handle_target_dir
    shutil.rmtree(target_item_dir)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/shutil.py", line 732, in rmtree
    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/shutil.py", line 660, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    _rmtree_safe_fd(dirfd, fullname, onerror)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/shutil.py", line 683, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/shutil.py", line 681, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    os.unlink(entry.name, dir_fd=topfd)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'configuration.py'
```

Comment: Try `sudo python3 get-pip.py`.

Comment: It shows that pip-22.3.1 is now installed, but when I try "pip" or "pip3" in the terminal, the same thing above shows up

Comment: Hm, try just `import pip` from python3.

Comment: What do you get typing `pip3` from shell?

Comment: Looks python path is not added to you environment. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387695/add-to-python-path-mac-os-x), might be helpful

Comment: Also try `/usr/local/bin/pip3`.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Sorry, I'm quite new to this. What do you mean by adding a python path to the environment?

Comment: @YuriGinsburg 'import pip' works from python3! /usr/local/bin/pip3 shows that there is no file or directory though. Would this mean pip is installed, but in a different directory?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
python -m pip uninstall [options] <package>
python -m pip uninstall [options] -r <requirements file>
```

For Example

```
python -m pip uninstall simplejson
```

[Reference](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_uninstall/)

Comment: OP has an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'`, so I do not think that `python -m pip` will work.

Comment: That worked! I uninstalled a library using this! However, when I try "python3 -m pip uninstall pip", it gives the following error:
-
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/shutil.py", line 825, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip-22.3.1.dist-info/' -> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/~ip-22.3.1.dist-info'